# Creating multiple data frames by providing a condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying create multiple data frames from a single data-frame. I managed to achieve the process by repeating the same line of code, but its looks tedious and is not time friendly. I want to create a loop that iterates through the data-frame and create dataframes for me.
Also I have a list of copy of my Intial dataframe(from which I want to create multiple dataframes).

```
df_list = [df_0run,df_1run,df_2run,df_3run,df_4run,df_5run,df_6run]
```

Please suggest an approach for my question.

```
df_0season1=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==1]
df_0season2=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==2]
df_0season3=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==3]
df_0season4=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==4]
df_0season5=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==5]
df_0season6=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==6]
df_0season7=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==7]
df_0season8=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==8]
df_0season9=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']==9]
```

In this fashion I want to create multiple dataframes, and return them as a list. or multiple lists.

**Required output**

```
Seasons list = [df_0season1,df_0season2,df_0season3,df_0season4,df_0season5,df_0season6,df_0season7,df_0season8,df_0season9, 
df_1season1,df_1season2,df_1season3,df_1season4,df_1season5,df_1season6,df_1season7,df_1season8,df_1season9, 
df_2season1,df_2season2,df_2season3,df_2season4,df_2season5,df_2season6,df_2season7,df_2season8,df_2season9, 
df_3season1,df_3season2,df_3season3,df_3season4,df_3season5,df_3season6,df_3season7,df_3season8,df_3season9, 
df_4season1,df_4season2,df_4season3,df_4season4,df_4season5,df_4season6,df_4season7,df_4season8,df_4season9,
 df_5season1,df_5season2,df_5season3,df_5season4,df_5season5,df_5season6,df_5season7,df_5season8,df_5season9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a little help of `exec` over here,

```
for i in range (1,10):
    exec("""df_0season{}=df_0run.loc[df_0run['Season_Id']=={}]""".format(i))
```

This is just a basic application of [exec](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/)
and you can modify it as your requirement.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much. But the list holds entire dataframe with the data, is there a way to store the datafram into a name say df_0season1